# Find and replace in a different line

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Lets say I have few lines where I have to select a string within braces and then use it to substitute it elsewhere few lines later

```
Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD)
Second line
Third line
Forth line 
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/destination/
few more lines
```

I want to pick `WORD` and substitute `destination` with `WORD`
so that it looks like this

```
Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD1)
Second line
Third line
Forth line 
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/WORD1/
few more lines

Also how can I do this for tis to be recurring in a same file
Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD2)
Second line
Third line
Forth line
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/WORD2/
few more lines

Here is another  word that I need to select in braces (WORD3)
Second set of lines
Third line
Forth line
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/WORD3/
few more lines and pattern repeats like this so on
```

Comment: This is a textbook example from the first or maybe second lesson in a basic Awk course. It should not be hard to find existing code examples. Realize that your sequence of lines constitute a "record" of related fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, sed works line by line. So in order to work with that patter you should make it to work with multiple lines. [See this Stackoverflow question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string).

A simpler alternative would be to use perl. Perl comes with almost any (if not all) linux distros and some UNIX systems.

So you may use this:

`perl -0777 -pe 's/([\s\S]*?\()([^)]+)(\)[\s\S]*?\/root\/usr\/)destination([\s\S]*?)/$1$2$3$2$4/g' file.txt`

The regex is this one:

`([\s\S]*?\()([^)]+)(\)[\s\S]*?\/root\/usr\/)destination([\s\S]*?)`

Replace by: `$1$2$3$2$4`

**[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/uIQS7t/2/)**

Comment: I have updated my question , also meanwhile I found the answer too but seems like its not replace ing after the first match and replace
```perl -0 -pe 's/(CREATE TABLE [a-z]+\.)([a-z\_]+)(\s[\s\S]*?\/user\/bbc\/test\/)ac(?ms)(.+?(?=^CREATE|\z))/$1$2$3$2$4/' replace.txt
```  https://regex101.com/r/THxa3r/1

Comment: That's because I though your input was the whole content, I didn't think that it could be repeated several times, so my quantifiers where greedy. I updated my question to make them lazy. I also removed the first option since it does not make sense now.

Comment: Also, the `g` flag was missing.

Comment: Note that `perl -0` should be `perl -0777`.

Comment: @Borodin changed, I just thought NUL would be safe enough

Comment: Can you explain both flags g and -0777

Comment: By default, when reading files, you read them line by line (separated by `\n`) With `-0` you will read from [NUL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) to NUL. Since  you probably won't find a NUL character on your file. This mean that you read the whole file at once. `-0` may be followed by 3 numbers. That will mean a character in octal. So in theory from `000` to `377` (0-255 decimal). So any number > than 377 will read the whole file, since it is impossible. Sometimes instead of 378 it is just easier to write 777 which is the max number for 3 digit octal number. @Fenomatik

Comment: @Fenomatik the `g` flag means `global`. It is used to repeat the replacement until the end of the string, instead of stop on first replacement

Answer (score 1):

I'm concerned about your invented input data as it doesn't seem even close to anything that the "answer" in your comment could process correctly. However, here's a solution that reads from the integral `DATA` file handle. I've read the file a line at a time instead of slurping the whole thing, as it makes it easier to pick up new replacement strings

The only other provisos are that

- The `destination` keyword never appears *before* the replacement word on the same line
- There is no need to distinguish occurrences of `destination` that are in a path string
- There are no parentheses in the input text except for those surrounding the replacement words

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $rep;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    $rep = $1 if /\(([^()]+)\)/;
    s/destination/$rep/g if defined $rep;
    print;
}


__DATA__
Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD1)
Second line
Third line
Forth line 
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/destination/
few more lines

Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD2)
Second line
Third line
Forth line 
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/destination/
few more lines

Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD3)
Second line
Third line
Forth line 
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/destination/
few more lines
```

#### output

```
Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD1)
Second line
Third line
Forth line
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/WORD1/
few more lines

Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD2)
Second line
Third line
Forth line
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/WORD2/
few more lines

Here is the word that I need to select in braces (WORD3)
Second line
Third line
Forth line
Path where I want it to replace /root/usr/WORD3/
few more lines
```

Although I recommend against using them, the one-liner version of this is

```
perl -pe '$rep = $1 if /\(([^()]+)\)/; s/destination/$rep/g if defined $rep;' myfile
```